# Multiple Directory Selection in QComboBox

Tags: python, pyside

I have a folder structure that is the same for vfx projects. I'm trying to make a little UI to open up files based on the folder structure. Here is where I am getting stuck:

I have 3 `QComboBox`. I'd like them to pull from the directory structure. My directory structure is `/mnt/sv01/projects_directory/*projectname/sequences/*seq###/*shot###/comp/filename.comp`

The asterisks are folder names that change and that I want the user to pick in the 3 separate comboboxes.

I lay out the first combobox like this:

```
fsm = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
index = fsm.setRootPath("/mnt/sv01/projects_directory")
self.project_combo.setModel(fsm)
self.project_combo.setRootModelIndex(index)
```

This correctly displays the Project folders in the combobox. The next part is where I am getting stuck.

```
self.project_combo.activated[str].connect(self.Directory)
def Directory(self,item):
    fsm2 = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
    index2 = fsm2.setRootPath(os.path.join("/mnt/sv01/projects_directory",item))
    self.seq_combo.setModel(fsm2)
    self.seq_combo.setRootModelIndex(index2)
```

I'm very new to python and really only know the very very very barebones. It looks like I can't use `os.path.join` in this situation but I need to move to the next directory in the combobox. If I do

```
index2 = fsm2.setRootPath("/mnt/sv01/projects_directory/" + item + "/")
```

It returns to here `/mnt/sv01/projects_directory/*projectname/sequences` with sequences being the thing that is in the combobox and not `*seq###.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it seems to always happen I figured out the crude way to do it (I'm sure).
I didn't go far enough. If I put the line in as
`index2 = fsm2.setRootPath("/mnt/sv01/projects_directory/" + item + "/sequences/")`
Then it finds the right folders. Boy, not clean at all but it works.